# php array not returning full out put

Tags: php, arrays, shell

I have a php code which will ssh to a remote machine and execute a shell script to get list of folders. The remote machine contain more than 300 folders in the specified path in the shell script.Shell script executes well and return the list of all folders.But while I retrieve this output in php, I'am getting only around 150, 200 number of folders.

Here is my php code,

```
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
    if(!($con = ssh2_connect("ip.add.re.ss", "port")))
    {
        echo "fail: unable to establish connection";
        }
    else
    {
        if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "username", "password"))
    {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate";
    }
    else
        {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($con, "/usr/local/listdomain/listproject.sh");
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $item = fread($stream,4096);
        $items = explode(" ", $item);
        print_r($items);
    }
        }
    ?>
```

And this is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(ls /home);
echo $var;
```

What is the issue with php here. Is there any limit in array size in php while getting data dynamically like here.Please advise as I am very beginner to PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a timeout happening?

Comment: You'll have trouble exploding your input if there are file or directory names with spaces. If you change your `ls` command to `ls --format-single-column /home` you can explode on newlines: `$items = explode("\n", $item);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only reading one block of 4096 characters from your stream. if your folder list is longer than this you'll lose the rest. You need something like this:

```
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $item = "";
    // continue reading while there's more data
    while ($input = fread($stream,4096)) {
       $item .= $input;
    }

    $items = explode(" ", $item);
    print_r($items);
```

Comment: I will try this and get you soon.

Comment: You'll have trouble exploding your input if there are file or directory names with spaces. If you change your `ls` command to `ls --format-single-column /home` you can explode on newlines: `$items = explode("\n", $item);`

Answer (score 0):

You asked [`fread()`](http://docs.php.net/fread) to only read 4096 bytes. In the examples portion of `fread()`’s documentation, it is suggested that [`stream_get_contents()`](http://docs.php.net/stream_get_contents) be used for reading a file handle out to its end. Otherwise, you have to use a loop and keep on reading data until `feof($stream)` returns `FALSE`.